# Caching is not working on Circle ci 2

Tags: android, circleci, circleci-2.0

Every time Circle Ci 2 run a build, Gradle downloads the dependencies even if the cache is enabled.

Does anyone have a clue on this, on how to prevent it from downloading it each time? Thanks.

[image: Circle build output]

full circle config file : https://gist.github.com/alouanemed/2b8ce7a154663ffd8b422f1b75748b4f

Comment: I can't find description of `&` syntax for referencing in docs: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/ Isn't that a problem?